# looping a function with different arguments in python

Tags: python, function, loops

I am trying to loop over a function with different numbers as arguments.
I want to test the numbers between 1 and 20 for example. What is the way to go?

```
def calculation(w):
     print_me_w = w+1
     print (print_me_w)

calculation(1)
```

Comment: You'll need a *for* loop and a *range*

Comment: Have you already heard about loops in python?
https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/controlflow.html#for-statements

Comment: Thank you for answering, you helped me out.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `range` builtin and `for` loop as follow:

```py
for i in range(1, 21):
    calculation(i)
```

Comment: Thank you for answering, you helped me out.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the range function for this.

```
def calculation(w):
    print_me_w = w+1
    print (print_me_w)

for i in range(1,21):
    calculation(i)
```

Comment: Thank you for answering, you helped me out.